# If $μ(\limsup_{n\geq1}A_n)=1,μ(\liminf_{n\geq1}B_n)=1 $ prove that $μ(\limsup_{n\geq1}(A_n\cap B_n))=1 $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $(X, \mathcal{A},μ)$ is probability space, $(Α_n)_n, (B_n)_n$ sequences of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $μ(\limsup_{n\geq1}A_n)=1,μ(\liminf_{n\geq1}B_n)=1 $

prove that $μ(\limsup_{n\geq1}(A_n\cap B_n))=1 $

That's what I tried: it suffices to prove that $μ(\liminf_{n\geq1}(A^c_{n}\cup B^c_{n}))=0$

$$\liminf_{n\geq1}(A^c_{n}\cup B^c_{n})=\cup_{{n\geq1}} \cap_{{k\geq n}} (A^c_{n}\cup B^c_{n})\subseteq \cup_{{n\geq1}}(A^c_{n}\cup B^c_{n})=\{\cup_{{n\geq1}}(A^c_{n})\}\cup\{\cup_{{n\geq1}}B^c_{n})\}$$ and wanted to prove that their measure is zero. Then I said that $μ(\liminf_{n\geq1}A^c_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}μ(\cap_{n\geq 1} A^c_n)=0 $ And tried simirarly for $\limsup B^c_n$.

Well, I ended up believing that I can't prove what I wanted with the above.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\limsup_{n\ge 1} (A_n\cap B_n)\supseteq \limsup_{n\ge 1} A_n \cap \liminf_{n\ge 1} B_n,
$$
$$
\mu\!\left(\limsup_{n\ge 1} (A_n\cap B_n)\right)\ge \mu\!\left(\limsup_{n\ge 1} A_n \cap \liminf_{n\ge 1} B_n\right)=1.
$$